# Скриншоты в Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Использую Java + Selenium Webdriver. Есть задача:

- Сделать 4 скриншота (с интервалом в 5 секунд).
- Для каждого скриншота получить и сохранить md5-хэш.
- Сравнить полученные значения хэшей (все должны быть разным).

Помогите разобраться, что и как зачем?

Чтобы сделать скриншот можно вызвать метод `getScreenshotAs(OutputType target)`:

```
File screenShot = ((TakesScreenshot) webDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
BufferedImage screenshotImage = ImageIO.read(screenShot);
```

1. В первой строке мы делаем скриншот.
2. Преобразовываем его в `BufferedImage` - Почему так нужно или не нужно делать?
3. Как мне сохранить скриншот на компьютер?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

код для шарпа(практически идентичный с джавой)

```
Screenshot myScreenShot = ((ITakesScreenshot)webDriver).GetScreenshot();
myScreenShot.SaveAsFile(screenShotFileAdress, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

закинь в цикл с Thread.Sleep(5000); в конце тела цикла.

с хешами сам разберешься (и не уверен что тебе вообще нужно сохранять изображения, лучше закинь их в какой-нибудь Лист и генери мд5 с битмапов, что б потом просто сравнять =) Сохранять сами изображения не обязательно )

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky какое именно утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

Пример из моего кода:

```
File srcfile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

FileUtils.copyFile(srcfile, new File("path_to_save" + "Screenshot_" + getTimeStamp() + ".png"));
```

Comment: Как быть с тем что ide не знает о FileUtils?
Импорт библиотек не предлагается. Это что-то стороннее?

Comment: @PavelBobrov
Подробнее https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.5

Answer (score 0):

```
// take a screen shot:
    File sceFile = driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy__hh_mm");
    String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    File targetFile = new File("path\\to\\screenshots\\" + dateFormat.format(new Date()) + fileName + ".jpg");
    FileUtils.copyFile(sceFile, targetFile);
```